# Accessing the state of AngularUI tab from within the elements it contains

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've used AngularUI to build Bootstrap-themed tabs:

```
<tabset>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>Javascript <span class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>Python <span class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>Ruby <span class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

See those `<span>`'s with `{{ count }}`? I'd like them to be shown *only* if their containing tab is selected (active). Something like this would be perfect:

```
<span ng-show="tab.active" class="badge">{{ count }}</span>
```

This does not work, so I wrote functions `$scope.setActiveTab` and `$scope.isTabActive` and now my code looks like this:

```
<tab select="setActiveTab(0)">
    <tab-heading>Javascript <span ng-show="isTabActive(0)" class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
</tab>
<tab select="setActiveTab(1)">
    <tab-heading>Python <span ng-show="isTabActive(1)" class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
</tab>
<tab select="setActiveTab(2)">
    <tab-heading>Ruby <span ng-show="isTabActive(2)" class="badge">{{ count }}</span></tab-heading>
</tab>
```

This works, but seems ugly. (Let alone this won't work with more than one tabset).

Is there a better way to access the state of the tab from within those spans?

Plunker with my current code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Id3aSU4NPcPNJO6gXuoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work a bit easier in an `ng-repeat`

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active">
...
ng-show="tab.active"
```

[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9XCP3UIAFZqHNHQiM8V?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! The code looks cleaner with `ng-repeat`.